# Issues Setting Up Apache For Iphone HTML5

Tags: macos, apache

I have been trying to follow the book "Beginning Iphone and Ipad Web Apps, Scripting with HTML5, CSS, and javascript" and I am having issues setting up apache correctly apparently. I am trying to do this with Mac OSX 10.6.8. Maybe I just dont understand how it's supposed to work but here is what I have done so far:

add to hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 www.app.local
127.0.0.1 www.myapp.local
```

In httpd.conf:

uncomment:

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule fastcgi_module     libexec/apache2/mod_fastcgi.so
```

Add:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/Danger/Server/www
    ServerName www.myapp.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Before I restart apache, when I go to www.app.local in my browser I see "It Works!" After I restart I get "Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server."

What is going on? The book says I should see a blank page, and then after adding index.php containing:

```
<?php 
    phpinfo();
?>
```

I should see a table containing the server info, but I still see Forbidden...

How can I fix this to get the desired result?

Comment: Do you have an `.htaccess` file in directory `/Users/Danger/Server/www`?  If yes, what is in that file?

Comment: I do not, what should be in that directory? The book never said anything about it.

Comment: Technically you don't need it.  Check your Apache configuration for `DocumentIndex`, since you are using PHP you will have to have at a minimum `DocumentIndex index.php` in your configuration or in the .htaccess file in the root of your site.  This tells Apache to run the file `index.php` if a directory is referenced.  Also, checkout [this web page](http://jonathanstegall.com/2009/11/04/default-htaccess-file-for-all-sites/) for more information on .htacess and what it can do.